# Filtering the results of zip in Scala 2

Tags: scala

In my scenario, there are three types: A, B and C with C being a subtype of A.

```
class C extends A
val a: Array[A] = ...
val b: Array[B] = ...
```

I've been trying to zip `a` and `b` first and then filter the results based on the type of the first element, but it seems I'm missing something here.

```
a.zip(b).filter(_: (A, B) => _._1.isInstanceOf[C]
```

This does not seem to work, since Scala completely disregards my type declaration for `_` on the left side to type `_` on the right side as `Array[(A, B)]`.

Since I know `isInstanceOf` is not the scala way of doing things, I also considered using `collect` like this:

```
a.zip(b).collect{case x: (C, B) => x}
```

But this does not work, since scala does expect the types `(A, B)` here, rendering the type matching useless.

I'm used to Python programming, so maybe my approach is off here. Would appreciate any pointer in the right direction.

Comment: BTW, as advice, use `List` or `Vector` or `ArraySeq` or any other real collection, instead of `Array`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`_` is an anonymous parameter, you don't "declare" it, so it's either this:

```
a.zip(b).filter(_._1.isInstanceOf[C])
```

or this:

```
a.zip(b).filter { x: (A, B) => x._1.isInstanceOf[C] }
```

(note curly braces too)

Can also write it with a partial function syntax:

```
a.zip(b).filter { case (a,b) => a.isInstanceOf[C] }
```

or (better):

```
a.zip(b).filter { 
   case (_: C, _) => true
   case _ => false
}
```

or use `collect` as you suggested:

```
a.zip(b).collect { case x@(_: C, _) => x }
```

Personally, I prefer the last option over others.